# Why does std::println(std::vector) fail to compile?

Tags: c++, stdvector, libc++, fmt, c++23

I have the following code:

```cpp
#include <print>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
    std::println("{}", v);
}
```

Among the numerous errors this produces, there is (`clang++ -std=c++23 -stdlib=libc++`, https://godbolt.org/z/3z9Tseh37):

```
[...]/format_arg_store.h:167:17: error: static assertion failed due to [...]
  167 |   static_assert(__arg != __arg_t::__none, "the supplied type is not formattable");
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This confuses me because according to the [cppreference C++23 compiler support page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/23), libc++ support `std::println` and implements [P2286: Formatting Ranges](https://wg21.link/P2286R8).

Am I doing something wrong or is this a standard library bug?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Am I doing something wrong or is this a standard library bug?

Formatting ranges are specified to be supported in `<format>`, but the standard does not specify that `<print>` must include `<format>`. (So just include `<format>` to make the code well-formed).

However, from a user-friendly perspective, including `<print>` should support formatting ranges.

There is already an open issue about this, see [71925](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/71925).

Comment: ran into this myself -- the error message is spectacularly unhelpful especially at a time where some compilers / libraries support print and some don't so it's easy to think that's what the problem is.